# VBA Internet Explorer clicking on Text Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and it would be great if you can help me on resolving this issue.
I am trying to click on a Text on an IE SharePoint webpage. I am am able to navigate to IE browser, but I am getting a VBA error for clicking the text "Americas" highlighted in Yellow in attached  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFjKe.png). I need help with the IE.Document part of the code at the end of VBA code below. I assume GetElementbyID and GetElementByTagName are correct from HTML code below.
Error - Method Document of Object "IEwebBrowser"Failed

VBA Code:

```
 Private Sub UploadFile()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim Doc As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object
    Dim buttonCollection As Object

    Dim AllSpanElements
    Dim Span

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    ' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
    IE.navigate "URL"

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    While IE.Busy
            DoEvents
    Wend

    ' I AM GETTING ERROR HERE
        Set AllSpanElements = IE.Document.getElementById("ext-gen1271").getElementsByTagName("div")
        AllSpanElements.Click

        Set IE = Nothing
        Set objElement = Nothing
 End Sub
```

HTML CODE

```
<table class="x-grid-table x-grid-table-resizer" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:10000px;"><tbody>
<tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-row-selected x-grid-row-focused" id="ext-gen1271">
<td class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1030   x-grid-cell-first">
<div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDA" class="x-tree-elbow-plus x-tree-expander">
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAA" class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-parent ">
Americas</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Try `Set AllSpanElements = IE.Document.getElementById("ext-gen1271").getElementsByTagName("div")(0)` instead. You need to specify a singular element to click it. The other option if that doesn't work is to iterate over the TagName collection and look for the inner text "Americas" then click it.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I have tried both methods and ended up getting the same error. Following is the code for iteration method.  <pre> Set AllSpanElements = IE.Document.getElementById("ext-gen1271").getElementsByTagName("div")(0)
    For Each Span In AllSpanElements
      
        If Span.innerText = "Americas" Then
          
                Span.Click
            Exit For
      End If
   Next <code>
' Getting Error - Method "Document" of Object "IEwebBrowser2" Failed

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot, I cleaned up the code slightly and I'm trying a slightly different approach. Basically I'm iterating over each element on the page, then clicking it when the `InnerText` has "Americas" contained with in it.

It may not be the InnerText Property you want to check, it might be the `Value` or `Title` so you will need to check that.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub UploadFile()
   Dim IE                  As Object: Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   Dim Elements            As Object
   Dim Element             As Object

   With IE
       .Visible = True
       ' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
       .navigate "URL"

       ' Wait while IE loading...
       While .Busy Or .readystate <> 4
           Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
           DoEvents
       Wend
   End With

   ' I AM GETTING ERROR HERE
   Set Elements = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("*") ' * is all elements
   For Each Element In Elements
       If InStr(1, Element.innerText, "Americas") > 0 Then ' If the element has the word Americas...click it
           Element.Focus
           Element.Click
           Element.FireEvent ("OnClick")
       End If
   Next

   'Clean up
   Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Ryan thanks a lot for the code. I really appreciate it.  I am not getting the error, but the clicking event is not happening. IE just opens the site that's it. Is it something to do with the tags?

Comment: You will need to check which property "Americas" is contained in. It could be another property other than InnerText. Put a breakpoint in and review the Element Object to see which properties are available. Usually InnerText and Value are the most common.

Comment: Also, I was getting the same error with your code but I replaced the Set IE part with the following code Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium. Now there is no error but its not clicking on "Americas"

Comment: I have put the break points and searched for properties but couldn't find it. Its strange that the code works for all the other click types as shown in the screenshot(Home, Manage Files, Search, favorites), but doesn't work for The inner Navigation menu items (Americas, ...). I not sure how to get the property for those items. May be sharepoint library issue?

Comment: Without looking at the site it's hard to say. Did you try changing `Element.innerText` to `Element.Value`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also checked for inner.HTML. I have attached the screenshot webpage.

Comment: I'd need to review the whole HTML.`InnerHTML` and `OuterHTML` is worth trying too.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your help. I think the data is being pulled from database and thats causing the issue, otherwise the code works fine for other buttons. I am planning to use MouseEvent click function to click the Americas button. I would really appreciate your help on this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398938/vba-ie-browser-mouseevent-click-automation